# Can you apply 男子汉 and 女汉子 to non-Chinese?

Tags: word-choice, usage, characters

The term 汉奸 probably only works for Han Chinese traitors, but what about other '汉's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SA9Dr7M2hlc for an example, Mongolian 乌兰托娅 singing about 汉子. While 汉 is the dominant ethnicity, in general it just means man.

Answer (score 3):

男子汉 means a manly guy, a strong man, or a courageous fighter.

The grammar doesn't seem natural in Chinese. It actually originated in a foreign language and borrowed to Chinese. Here is some text about its origin:

据考证称呼成年男子为男子汉起源于汉武帝时代，众所周知自汉高祖刘邦白登被围后，西汉政权对北主的匈奴一直采取的和亲战略，因此匈奴人对汉人十分瞧不起，到武帝时期经过前几代皇帝的休养生息，西汉国力强盛，士卒训练有素，在汉武帝的命令下，西汉军队在卫青、霍去病两位将军的带领下，与北方的匈奴展开了激烈的战争，经过数次大战终于打败了强大的匈奴，当时的汉朝军队士兵战斗力强悍，在对战中经常以一敌二或敌三，死战不退，一扫有汉以来匈奴人对汉人的蔑视态度，因此从那时起匈奴人对汉朝士兵的称呼即为“汉儿”、“男儿汉”，此称呼后来传回中原，风靡一时，后来人们逐渐对成年男子即用男子汉称呼。

It can be used for people of any ethnicity in China (not just 汉族，but also 满族、蒙古族, etc). So foreigners can also use the word without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you apply 男子汉 and 女汉子 to non-Chinese?

Yes.

Originally the 汉 in those words mean 'man of Han dynasty', however, today that connotation is completely gone. You can apply these words on people with any nationality or ethnicity.

Answer (score 2):

汉 has different meanings in these phrases.

In 汉奸，汉 stands for the ethnicity (or probably the nationality), but in 男子汉 and 女汉子，汉 or 汉子 means masculinity.  I am not sure of the relation between these two meanings, but they are surely different.

Answer (score -1):

男子汉 means a man whose body or inspire is strong and who has no fear to face the difficulties.But the word"女汉子" means different.First of all, it is a word about the girl,and second, it means the girl acts like a man.